# GPUs and software for FAST realtime VisFX?

Tags: effects

This question obviously is highly dependent on specific VisFX's, so please answer IN GENERAL:

**In general, which GPUs/GPU families and software (Mac, Windows, Linux) COMBINATIONS are best for rendering a large variety of VisFX in realtime on a live video feed (from a tethered camera)?**

I'm asking in order to choose a netbook to purchase for realtime VisFX on a live feed; netbooks are fundamentally limited in GPU/CPU power, so I want to find a GPU/software combination that works most efficiently.

Comment: Although you've specifically requested that we answer 'in general', it is nigh on impossible to do so with the information you have provided. For starters, what software will you be streaming in, and what resolution will it be? What are you using to produce the effects?

Comment: I asked about COMBINATIONS of hardware and software in order to open up the domain and allow this question to find the FASTEST setups for live video VisFX.  For the purpose of this question, assume 720p  24fps, with whatever hardware, software, and OS can most quickly get a feed from the camera into a realtime VisFX process.  That should be enough to specify the question.